# How to add google OAuth2.0 support in my CAS server

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using jasig cas4.0 server. I have implemented the Facebook oAuth2.0 support in my cas server and it works correctly. Now, I want to add Google oauth support (Google2Client) in the same CAS-server.

1) I created a new Project in console.developers.google.com, created a new client id under the OAuth with redirect uri to https://rajan.com:1443/cas/login (which actually points to localhost)

2) I added this to my applicationcontext.xml

```
 <bean id="google1" class="org.pac4j.oauth.client.Google2Client">
  <property name="key" value="<<CLIENT_ID>>" />
  <property name="secret" value="<CLIENT_SECRET" />
  <property name="scope" value="email" />
  <property name="fields" value="id,name,first_name,middle_name,last_name,gender,email" />
</bean>
```

I also registered this bean in the clients

```
<bean id="clients" class="org.pac4j.core.client.Clients">
  <property name="callbackUrl" value="https://rajan.com:1443/cas/login" />
  <property name="clients">
    <list>
      <ref bean="facebook1" />
      <ref bean="google1" />

    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

3) And finally, I added this in casLoginView.jsp

```
<a href="${FacebookClientUrl}">Authenticate with Facebook</a> <br />
<a href="${Google2ClientUrl}">Authenticate with Google</a> <br />
```

But, When I open the cas login view in the browser, the  href for Google contains "https://rajan.com:1443/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Frajan.com%3A2443%2FCasClientSimple%2F" instead of Google Oauth url. The facebook link works fine.

Could someone help me what I am missing here.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the Google2OauthClient. There were no **fields** property.

So, just deleting the fields property in the above bean worked.
I also changed the field **email**  with **EMAIL_AND_PROFILE**